Problems with Captive Portal on pfSense
I need help configuring the Captive Portal on the pfSense Firewall. What I need? I need to put Captive Portal on some access points to prevent users from using Wi-Fi.
I've already tried to create a Captive portal on a LAN connection, but nothing happened. I don't know if I need to create some firewall rules or something else...
I think I've tried everything, but nothing works. Please someone help me.
I saw a lot of videos talking about it, but I tried a big part o the videos and nothing happend

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
